# Яка різниця між значеннями слів «мабуть» і «напевно»? Чи можна використовувати обох для вираження невпевненості?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

Англійська у мене краща мова, і часто я користуюся словом «probably» для вираження невпевненості але це не те саме що значить слово «maybe». «probably» я думаю виражає більше впевненості ніж «мaybe»

Російською я кажу «может быть» як еквівалент слову «maybe», а «наверно» як еквівалент слову «probably».

Я не знаю чому але українською я часто говорю «мабуть» в тому ж сенсі як і «может быть/maybe», і «напевно» в тому ж сенсі як і «наверно/probably».

Але, читаючи значення слова «напевно» в словниках, здається мені що це слово більш аналогічне словам «точно/definitely» і виражає повну впевненість у чомусь і в таких випадках я опускаю такі слова. В англійській якщо впевнений в чомусь, тоді здебільшого кажеш наприклад «He went to the store», а не «He definitely went to the store”.

Може хтось надати декілька простих речень/прикладів та пояснити як саме вживати ці слова?

Вибачте за помилки. Сподіваюся питання достатньо зрозуміле. Через те що я виріс у Канаді, слова з цих трьох мов часто в моїй голові плутаються.

Comment: Я хотів би запропонувати до використання ще два слова. *Імовірно* як прямий переклад/відповідник *probably*. І *вірогідно* -- те, що *віри гідно*, тобто таке ймовірність чого сягає десь 99%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Якщо коротко. Коли звичайний прислівник, то *напевно* — *certainly*, *definitely* ітд. А коли як [вставне слово](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE), котре ві вимові зазвичай видїляється короткими павзами чи інтонацією, відірваністю від загального речення, а в письмі — комами, то — *probably*, *likely* ітд. Знизу також будуть приклади.

> [*Уроки державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)*](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53405/25589.html)
>
> **НАПЕВНО**
>
> Коли слово *напевно* (*напевне*) відокремлюється комами, а коли — ні?
>
> Як прислівник у значенні *точно, безперечно, неодмінно, не боячись помилитися* не відокремлюється.
>
> *Павлина, хоч і напевно знала, що він отримав свої вісім злотих, вийшла дуже незадоволена з дому Річинських* (Ірина Вільде), *Та я ж таки тебе напевне бачив!* (Леся Українка).
>
> Як вставне слово для вираження ймовірності чогось відокремлюється.
>
> *Сагайда дізнався, що полк вийшов у другий ешелон і стоятиме тут, напевне, до завтра* (Олесь Гончар).

> [*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 140.*](http://sum.in.ua/s/napevno)
>
> **НАПЕВНО**, *прислівник*.
>
> 1. Точно, безперечно, безсумнівно.
>
>    *— Ну, моя матінко! Ізнайшла вже я чоловіка, що мене визволить... Напевно вам говорю, що визволить…* (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 267); *Однак новина впала, як грім з ясного неба. Тепер вже напевно* (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 95); *Павлина, хоч і напевно знала, що отримає свої вісім злотих, вийшла дуже незадоволена з дому Річинських* (Ірина Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 344);
>
>    //  Неодмінно, обов'язково.
>
>    *Танки в ліс не пройдуть, втрати в живій силі будуть незначні, плацдарм буде втримано напевно* (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 367).
> 2. З упевненістю, не боячись помилитися.
>
>    *Вона сміливо робить новий ривок. Якщо кіт біля комори, значить, немає поблизу людей і діяти можна напевно* (Іван Цюпа, Назустріч.., 1958, 193).
> 3. *у значенні вставного слова* Уживається для вираження ймовірності чого-небудь.
>
>    *Не знаю, що писати Вам далі. Звісно, я міг би написати цілу повість життя, але цей шлях дуже далеко завів би, — я і так боюся, що подав вам багато зайвого і вже, напевно, нецікавого* (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 234); *Йому, напевно, важко, цьому худорлявому кельнерові, але він все ж говорить* (Петро Колесник, На фронті.., 1959, 8).

Слово *мабуть* завжди вставне слово, тому є повним синонімом до вставного *(на)певно*. Можна також згадати такі слова як *здається*, *либонь*.

> [*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 587.*](http://sum.in.ua/s/mabutj)
>
> **МА́БУ́ТЬ**, діалектне **МА́БІ́ТЬ**, *вставне слово*
>
> Уживається для вираження невпевненості в тому, про що говориться в реченні; певно, очевидно.
>
> *Спала й виглядала Козаченька молодого, Що торік покинув. Обіщався вернутися, Та, мабуть, і згинув!* (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 3); *В дорогу Григорій узяв чимало всякого харчу, але більше всього тютюну; та чи не найбільше, мабуть, запасся терпінням* (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 76).

Коли що, *мабуть* то є усталена [скорочена форма](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C#11276), що походить від *має бути* — *[it] has/should to be*. Вираз *має бути* використовується понинї і дещо подібний до невставного *напевно*:

> — Де він?
> —  [Зараз] він має ідти до крамницї.

Тут дїєслово *піти* перебрало на собі функції *бути*, тому слово *бути* зникає, якщо то не [давньоминулий час](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81).

Якщо субʼєктивно, так і з тлумачення описів, то *мабуть* акцентує увагу на невпевненість мовця, а *напевно* — на імовірність того, що згадано в реченнї. Але, знов ж таки, ті слова переважно прямі синоніми.

Коли упустити подібні вставки, тобто сказати щось на зразок: *він пішов до крамницї*, то це сприймається радше як просто *факт*, що незалежний від мовця. І так можна відповідати, як і зазвичай роблять. Але якщо мовцю хочеться передати чи підкрїпити свою не/впевненість в цей факт, тоді додає відповідні слова.

Comment: "Дїєслово піти перебрало на собі функції бути, тому слово зникло" - як це зникло?

Comment: Слово _бути_, в тому числї в анґлійській, зазвичай є уставним замінником дїєслів, якщо їх немає. Якщо зʼявляється якесь дїєслово, то _бути_ зникає. Пор. _я [є] тут_ → _Я співаю тут_; _I should be here_ → _I should sing here_.

Comment: Таким чином, "напевно" у значенні прислівника можна перекласти російською як "наверняка". Цікаво, що слово поєднює у собі протилежні значення — впевненість (як прислівник) і невпевненість (як вставне слово) :)